# How do I hide comment button at the bottom of AMP post in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I've disabled comments on our WordPress site and we still have a "Leave a Comment" button appearing at the bottom of our AMP posts. See example here: https://adcreview.com/news/triphases-trph-222-a-site-specific-anti-cd22-adc-enters-clinical-phase-i-trials/amp/

How can I remove this "Leave a Comment" button from AMP posts throughout our site?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable comments globally by adding this line in your theme's functions.php file:

```
 add_filter('comments_open', '__return_false');
```

This should remove the button in your amp page.

Regards,

Comment: This filter disabling comments globally along with non-AMP (regular) pages.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, put in your theme's function.php file:

```
function amp_remove_comments_link( $meta_parts ) {
    unset( $meta_parts[ 'meta-comments-link' ] );
    return $meta_parts;
}
add_filter( 'amp_post_article_footer_meta', 'amp_remove_comments_link' );
```

Refer: https://github.com/ampproject/amp-wp/blob/develop/templates/single.php

Comment: Tried this in both the child theme and parent theme and it did not work.